# Create js object with kotlin/js without fields by default

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

Is it possible to create class in Kotlin, that will not add field without value to js object?  This is what I mean:

```
class ClassWithDefaultField (val fieldUndefined : String? = undefined)
class EmptyClass ()  
    
val withStringValue = ClassWithDefaultField("some_string")
val withDefaultValue = ClassWithDefaultField()
val emptyClassObject = EmptyClass()

console.log(withStringValue)
console.log(withDefaultValue)
console.log(emptyClassObject)
```

Output of this code:

```
{fieldUndefined: 'some_string'}
{fieldUndefined: undefined}
{}
```

What I want to achieve:

```
{fieldUndefined: 'some_string'}
{}
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only option I came up with:

```
class ClassWithDefaultField private constructor(
    val fieldUndefined : String? = undefined
) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(
            fieldUndefined : String? = undefined
        ): ClassWithDefaultField {
            return clone(ClassWithDefaultField(fieldUndefined))
        }
    }
}
```

Call to function ClassWithDefaultField() looks like a call to constructor, but it is not) But I don't like this solution, sure there must be a better one.